What is the rated current in (parenthesis) referring to?
I'm looking at an electricity meter and it states its rated current as 10(60) amps. See the image below. I'd be inclined to go with the idea that I shouldn't use it to measure the power for the whole house, but what is the "(60)" in reference to?


It's difficult to say without a part number of full datasheet to reference... but I'd guess it's the allowable peak / surge current that can be handled for a short duration (i.e: seconds).

You have to provide the source for that image.

The relevant National Standard refers to basic and maximum currents, so I suspect they refer to those limits. The accuracy requirements are a bit different depending on the current level and the power factor. Image is from a ppt summary of the standard DLT614-2007.

I believe the testing requirement says 2 minutes for Imax and that Imax should be 10x Ib so perhaps this product is not fully compliant, however this is subject to correction by someone fluent in the language of the documents.
